# Meaning of $\phi / \theta$ where $\phi$,$\theta$ are congruence relations

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need an interpretation for the expression $\phi / \theta$ where $\phi$ and $\theta$ are congruence relations which satisfy $\theta \subsetneq \phi$.

I know for a set $M$ and a Relation $R$ with $M/R$ is the quotientspace or in other words the set of all equivalence classes. But I'm not sure how the Relation "acts" on other 2-tupels.

Some help would be nice!

Comment: I’m feeling that I need more information. What is a congruence relation in this context? Are you talking about congruences among integers? Or is this some much more general situation?

Comment: I want to understand this if possible for a general situation. In my algebra course a congruence relation is an equivalence relation which is compatible with the operations which are defined to act on a set.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to answere my question if I state the situation of the exercise: There is given a partial order of 8-element set which defines a lattice. I should find two distinct non-trivial ralations $\theta$ and $\phi$ and than determine $V/ \phi$,$V/ \theta$ and $\phi / \theta$. I have found two congruence relation and the sets of their equivalence classes, determine the last expression is the  problem I already stated.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this simple example will help you to understand the general case.
Consider on $\mathbb{Z}$ the equivalence relations $R_2$ and $R_6$ defined by
\begin{align}
  x \mathrel{R_2} y &\iff x \equiv y \bmod 2 \\
  x \mathrel{R_6} y &\iff x \equiv y \bmod 6
\end{align}
Clearly $R_6 \subset R_2$. Now, $\mathbb{Z}/R_6 = \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$. The relation $R_2/R_6$ is the relation induced on $\mathbb{Z}/R_6$ by the relation $R_2$ on $\mathbb{Z}$: its two classes, namely
$\{0, 2, 4\}$ and $\{1, 3, 5\}$ are obtained by considering the classes modulo $6$ of the sets of even (respectively odd) integers.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your notation correctly: $\mathbb{Z} / R_6$ is the set of all equivalence classes are your writting $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$  where $0,1,2,3,...$ are representative for each equivalence class?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Just found a lemma in an algebra book which solves my problem:

Let $\phi$, $\theta$ be congruence relations on an algebra $\mathfrak{A}$ with $\theta \subset \phi$. Then the relation $\phi / \theta := \{([a]_{ \theta },[b]_{\theta})\vert(a,b) \in \phi\}$ is a congruence relation on $\mathfrak{A}/\theta$.

Comment: Would you tell us which algebra book?

Comment: Well it's technically not a book but the lecture notes of an algebra professor of my university. (They are over 400 pages long that's probably why I wrote book.) Here is the link: https://dmg.tuwien.ac.at/winkler/skripten/algebra.pdf 
Unfortunately it is written in german, there is no english version of it.